# Laravel Auth field role not recognized

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I created a table of users and I added a field called role and this line of code will not work when I use it in a filter, the problem is in the Auth::user()->role part

```
Route::filter('products.admin', function()
{ 
    if (Auth::user()->role !== 'admin')
        return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

Does any one know how to get the role field to be recognized for the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have a `role` field in your table, you should probably use:

```
Route::filter('products.admin', function()
{ 
    if (!Auth::check() || Auth::user()->role != 'admin')
        return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have something like this in your routes:

```
Route::get('products', array('before' => 'auth|products.admin', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@index'));
```

This way, you first check the user is authenticated and then you check that it has the correct role.

Comment: He doesn't *need* to, but it's the recommended way.

Comment: That's the sense in which I was using "have". At least let's help people with some good practices advice, right?